Angular DevTools not showing original .ts source files, only instrument.js in console logs
In my Angular application, I can't see the original .ts source files when I open the browser DevTools. Previously, if I added a console.log, it would display the original .ts file in the console, but now it shows instrument.js instead of the actual source file.
Details:
Angular: Version 9
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA
Browsers tested: Chrome, Firefox, etc.
Source maps: I have sourceMap: true in my Angular configuration, and I haven’t changed any settings recently.
Issue appeared: It was working fine before, but today it suddenly stopped.
Attempted fixes:
Verified sourceMap: true in angular.json
Cleared the browser cache and reloaded
Restarted the IDE and browser


it's clearly a problem with source maps. Check your Angular configurations in angular.json and tsconfig.*.json files, make sure that sourcemaps are enabled everywhere.
